# String with strange format to array

Tags: c#

I have this string:

```
string s = "[\"default\",\"direct\"]";
```

I want to make an array, **so the final array should be this:**

```
["default", "direct"]
```

#### What I have tried:

```
string[] ss = s.Split(',');
```

But the result is:

[image]

Comment: Remove [, ] and " characters, then split?

Comment: That's just the debugger. Write it to the console or click the loupe in the debugger and you'll see that it's what you expect.

Comment: @TimSchmelter so you mean the result in my case is the final result that I need ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I will try to made a loop and update you.

Comment: I personally would rather go for a JSON Library like [Json.Net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) ([Docs](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)) and then deserialize it to IList<string> or a more concrete type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have is JSON array. You can simply deserialize it with [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) (you can add it from NuGet):

```
string s = "[\"default\",\"direct\"]";
string[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(s);
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer though I didn't try it yet. because the string is comming from jquery json request. let me try

Comment: I don't have JsonConvert class

Comment: I alreay imported json.net library to my project, but vs2012 didn't suggest include it

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I added link to this library. You can get it from NuGet (its one of top-downloaded, easy to find). Namespace is `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Comment: wait wait sorry, I include that library in another project, let me in clude it in this project and I will udpate you. thanks

Comment: excellent it works perfectly, you the one man. Thanks really, +1 will accept when the system allows

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the JArray.

```
  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray jsonarr = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(jsonResult);
```